# Python Remove Column from Numpy Array based on some Condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The Title says it all.

Suppose  I have a numpy array containing values summing up to 1.

```
[0.5  0.3  0.1  0.05  0.03  0.01]
```

And I would want to remove all Values of the array which are smaller than 0.05
and at the same time remove the corresponding column, which leads to an array
like this:

```
[0.5  0.3  0.1  0.05]
```

There are of course ways to achieve this. But I'm not happy with the code I've 
produced thus far. I feel like there must be an elegant way to achieve this with
Python.

Thx for the help

**Edit:**

Thanks for the help. I feel like I was already on the right track. I just didn't 
know how to use the Syntax yet. Don't understand the down votes though. :(

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the ways that you've tried before. Perhaps even pointing out what you are unhappy with in them.

Comment: Well I've bin googling for quite some time now. And I saw notations like X[X > 1] = 5, which helps replace values but for actually deleting columns, I couldn't think of any way but to do a for loop combined with an if-clause and use numpy.delete, which seems kinda clumsy compared to all the pythonic sugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [0.5  0.3  0.1  0.05  0.03  0.01]
print a[a >= .05]
```

Comment: Thanx. It works when typed in the shell. Seems like somethings wrong with my code though. :/

Comment: make sure it's a numpy array. you can even just print `a >= .05` to see further how it works.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a 2D array (judging from the phrase, *"and at the same time remove the corresponding column*").

If you create a boolean array, `idx` which is True for the columns you wish to keep, then you can select just those columns using `arr[:, idx]`:

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{:0.2f}'.format})
np.random.seed(1)

arr = np.random.random((3,4))
mask = (arr < 0.05)
idx = mask.any(axis=0)
result = arr[:, ~idx]

print(arr)
# [[0.42 0.72 0.00 0.30]
#  [0.15 0.09 0.19 0.35]
#  [0.40 0.54 0.42 0.69]]

print(result)
# [[0.42 0.72 0.30]
#  [0.15 0.09 0.35]
#  [0.40 0.54 0.69]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.delete` is your friend

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.5 , 0.3 , 0.1 , 0.05,  0.03,  0.01])
a = np.delete(a,np.where(a < 0.05))
```

`np.delete(a, 1)` will create a copy of `a`, then delete `a[1]` from the copy.
`a` is still unaffected.
To force the change in `a`, do 
we do `a = np.delete(a,np.where(a < 0.05))`

Also `np.delete` works for high dimensional arrays as well.
For high dimensional data, you have to do more work about choosing the correct `np.where`